# how to use streamline in matlab correctly

Tags: matlab

i have problem using streamline in matlab. my problem is i have vector field that compute u,v,x,y from a loop with a specific math function. i use this code to figure vector field :

```
quiver(x,y,u,v)
```

and it is get good answer and my answer is converge. but when i want to figure streamline with this code:

```
startx=-100;
starty=-100;
streamline(x,y,u,v,startx,starty)
```

i got this error:

```
Error using griddedInterpolant
Interpolation requires at least two sample points in each dimension.

    Error in interp1 (line 183)
            F = griddedInterpolant(X,V,method);

    Error in stream2 (line 62)
        sxi=interp1(xx(:),1:szu(2),sx(k));

    Error in streamline (line 62)
          verts = stream2(x,y,u,v,sx,sy,options);

    Error in  (line 44)
    streamline(x,y,u,v,startx,starty)
```

thanks in advance.
Best Regard

Comment: I could solve this by using meshgrid instead of ndgrid to generate my X-, Y-Coordinates. I'm not sure why it now works because the difference is only the orientation.